# How can I find the price of non-english cards?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have several German cards, from Unlimited - Fourth. How can I tell the price of German (ex. [Hypnotic Specter](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Hypnotic%20Specter))? [TCGplayer's website](http://shop.tcgplayer.com/magic/product/show?productname=hypnotic%20specter) doesn't appear to have much data for foreign language cards.

Comment: > "TCGplayer's website doesn't appear to have a foreign language option."

?? There's a product language box on the leftmost bar.

Comment: @HaoYe I tried checking the German box for that option and all of the results said "4 Total Prices Available. This product has no pricing options based on the filters you selected. Please adjust your filters to see more options." So while it technically has the option it doesn't really help (at least for this card)

Comment: That's because nobody has one for sale. If there's none for sale then there's no price. You should list yours, then there will be a price. And you can set the price at whatever you'd like to be paid for it.

Answer (score 1):

[Starcitygames.com](http://starcitygames.com) has a built-in foreign language price/ordering. The [search page for Hypnotic Specter](http://sales.starcitygames.com/search.php?substring=Hypnotic%20Specter&t_all=All&start_date=2010-01-29&end_date=2012-04-22&order_1=finish&limit=25&action=Show%2BDecks&card_qty%5B1%5D=1&auto=Y) has a link to the [old german version](http://sales.starcitygames.com/carddisplay.php?product=140922).

Comment: Please note that the prices in North America can be very different to the prices in Europe. If you plan on selling/trading in Europe, use the prices of EU-based shops like magiccardmarket.eu

Answer (score 1):

https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/ is widely used as the authoritative* price for non-English product. They are a market place and will typically have many sellers for most big name cards in many languages.

* That isn't to say that there isn't many weird prices to be found, you still need to use your head.

Comment: Please note that the prices in Europe can be very different to the prices in North America. If you plan on selling/trading in North America, use the prices of US-based shops like TCGPlayer or StarCityGames.

Comment: The same complaint could be made of the other answer with the regions reversed :)

Comment: It wasn't meant to be a complaint, just advice for OP. Since they were already using TCGPlayer, I assumed they are selling in North America.